# "www-authenticate →Bearer" with Unauthorized 401

Tags: azure, single-sign-on

I am trying to use Microsoft SSO with Azure Active Directory to authenticate users and also authorize API access. But I am stuck with token validation at the time of accessing the API. I get `401 Unauthorized` 
error with below response header

> content-length →0 
>   date →Tue, 28 Jan 2020 04:49:20 GMT
>   server →Kestrel
>   www-authenticate →Bearer

What is the cause of this error? I am using postman to hit the API with the token. The token is valid on jwt.io but still I am not able to access the APIs.

Below is the token:
[token at jwt.io](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsr9K.jpg)

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: How have you configured authentication on the API? Can you share the code?

Comment: I just used the [Authorize] attribute on the API. Also used **             services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme).AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureActiveDirectory", options));
** in Startup.cs.

Comment: You'll have to check your authentication configuration against the claims in the token. The valid audience should be what is in the token for example.

Comment: @juunas I was getting the errors like "invalid audience" and "invalid signature". I sorted them out but now this response header is not showing that what is the cause of unauthorization. On the Azure portal, in token configuration I have not added any other claims except the defaults.

Answer (score 3):

I was running into this problem, where I had to sort out "invalid issuer" and then just got a plan "www-authenticate: Bearer" 401.

To solve it, I had to call `app.UseAuthentication()` before `app.UseAuthorization()` in `Startup.Configure()` for my API app. After that it would go through.

It might be nice if that were mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration.

My thought is that the application needs to authenticate you before it can tell if you should be authorized or not, so if that's not there it will fail authorization.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer for this question..